# JavaScript Canvas requestAnimationFrame freezing tab

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, freeze, requestanimationframe

I've been working on a 2D game in JavaScript using the canvas, and I found that requestAnimationFrame seems to make the game much smoother, which is great. However, the game has been freezing at random times ever since. The tab becomes stuck, and the game doesn't throw any errors, so I'm kind of at a loss. I have tried many things to manually debug it, such as constantly updating a LocalStorage variable, just displaying in the console, etc. Nothing is really giving me any results.

I can say that my experiments lead me to believe that there may be some strange asynchronous behavior associated with requestAnimationFrame; namely, I have noticed that if I change the size of something via socket.on, such as an array, and the game happens to be running a for-loop on that array, it sometimes crashes mid for-loop saying that the thing I'm referencing is undefined, even though I check for that right before the for-loop. Moreover, I noticed that when requestAnimationFrame calls code, such as my Game.update() function, sometimes the "this" object isn't properly referencing the object I'm in. ie., in Game.update(), this.draw_something() would throw an error. I have fixed those issues I believe, but I'm wondering if anyone has any insight into the overall nature of requestAnimationFrame.

The last thing I want to mention is that when the tab freezes, the memory begins to sky-rocket. It quickly goes from a few hundred MBs (from pre-loaded gfx, etc) to around 2 gigs, and continually increases.

I hope someone has some good feedback - and thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Is `cancelAnimationFrame` called within `javascript`?

Comment: always use requestAnimationFrame with a recursive function. show us your code

Comment: Ideally you call requestAnimationFrame once a frame giving it the function that is your current main loop. From your main loop you do everything that needs to be done per-frame, then call requestAnimationFrame again. Calling it more than once can become tricky especially if any of the functions it calls back run over 1/60th of a second or the total time for all the calls goes over a frame. Also Javascript is blocking, while a loop is running nothing can change anything apart from what is being done in the loop.

Comment: I'm doing the following. But I have also tried calling requestAnimationFrame at the end of the loop:display: function() {
  try{
   var t = new Date().getTime();
   Game.displaying = true;

   if (!Game.paused){
    Game.frame_id = window.requestAnimationFrame(Game.display);
   }

   Game.update();

   Game.display_ctx = get_context('display-canvas');
   if (Game.display_ctx == null){
    alert('display-canvas has vanished.');
    Game.pause();
   } else {
    Game.present_map(Game.display_ctx);
   }
   
   Game.displaying = false;
  } catch (err){
   
  }
 },

Comment: As far as I can tell, the way I'm doing this seems quite standard. And I've noticed that it freezes when other canvases are displayed sometimes. For example, I have one canvas that is hidden or revealed when you click a certain button, and I've noticed that clicking the button sometimes freezes the game. It's very strange.

Comment: @JamesSiene, had the same problem as you did till I removed the second canvas that i used. Thanks for your solution